# Setuptools entry_points/console_scripts have specific Python version in shebang

Tags: python, setuptools

I am generating a Python package on RHEL6 (with Python2.6), and trying to deploy it to a RHEL7 server (Python2.7). The package includes scripts generated with entry_points/console_scripts.

However, the generated scripts have the specific python2.6 version in the shebang, as in:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.6
```

How can I override or disable this so it just generates:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17237878/changing-console-script-entry-point-interpreter-for-packaging

Answer (score 4):

```
entry_points = {
    'console_scripts':[
        ...        
        ]
},
options = {
    'build_scripts': {
        'executable': '/usr/bin/env python',
    },
},
```